# How much of a symbiotic relationship was there between the Renaissance and the Printing Press?

Tags: 15th-century, renaissance, inventions

Both the Renaissance and the Printing Press are dated to be around the 14th century. While the first Printing Press was in 1436 (Johannes Gutenberg), the Renaissance is also supposed to start around a similar time-frame. I suspect that both influenced the right of the other.

Is it true, that the Renaissance was influenced as scientific ideas were more easily propagated than they had been in the past? It would be interesting to know one way or the other!

Comment: Did you ask this question just for me? :-)

Comment: if you can answer it, why not :)

Comment: I am personally of the *opinion*, and have brought it up on probably an absurd amount of answers here, that nearly every component of what we call "The Renaissance" was a **result of** the Printing Press.

Comment: @T.E.D. I am not so sure. Valuable as it was, the spread of the printing press took its time, and the production of the books themselves also needed some considerable time. Yes by 1500 there were lots of printing presses and books edited, but by that time the Renaissance had been going on for quite some time. Also, if the printing press were that determinant, you would expect the Renaissance to have developed in Germany/Central Europe and not in Italy.

Comment: came to know that at least https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Officiis made some contribution to the Renaissance movement which was the second book printed after the Gutenberg Bible.

Comment: Printing press is impossible without enough population capable of reading. The need of reading and writing was the result of merchant cities who needed people capable to perform the tasks of accountants. Therefore I think that both phenomena (Renaissance and Printing Press) are not directly related.

Comment: @Santiago - That is indeed one of the better counter-arguments. I think I could address it (eg: you could likewise ask how important is the Internet when almost nobody had their own computer and network access when it was invented), but SE answers (and comments) aren't a great forum for that.

Comment: @T.E.D. are you planning to answer this?  I have found several sources and one seemingly authoritative book on exactly this subject which, while not entirely supporting your premise, comes pretty close. But I don't want to tread into your territory if you are working on an answer since you probably can address this better than I could.